# What wysiwyg editor can I use for my rails 3.1 app with support of image uploader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, editor, wysiwyg, image-uploading

I tried this [editor](https://github.com/sandipransing/rails_tiny_mce), but received many errors, maybe existing some editor, which I can easy install and update images.

My answer: 
Now I use [this editor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), very easy to install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im using tinymce with the [gem `'tiny_mce'`](https://github.com/kete/tiny_mce) and `carrierwave` for image upload.
My setup for tinymce is following:

```
$(function() {
  tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    editor_deselector: "plain",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "advimage,inlinepopups,save,autosave",
    external_image_list_url: '#{image_list_admin_static_images_url}',
    relative_urls: false,

    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons22: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_blockformats: "p,h2,h3,h4"
  })
}
```

The important part is `image_list_admin_static_images_url` in my routes i have:

```
resources :static_images do
      get :image_list, :on => :collection
end
```

Method in StaticImagesController looks like:

```
 def image_list
    @image_list = "var tinyMCEImageList = #{StaticImage.image_list.to_json}"
    render :js => @image_list
 end
```

And in image_list method located in the model:

```
 def self.image_list
    all.map{ |im| [im.alt, im.image.url] }
 end
```

This setup works perfectly for me, ofc you need to customize it for your own needs. Hope this will help you. TinyMCE is really nice and powerfull wysiwyg editor.

As `chech` suggested in the comments section, here is how you can adjust this solution for use with `active_admin`:

To use it inside active admin simply replace the route for this one:
 `match "admin/model_name/:id/js_image_list", :action => "js_image_list", :controller => "admin/model_name"`. Then create an action called `js_image_list` inside the active admin model file. Configuration for tinyMCE.init is: `external_image_list_url : "js_image_list"`

Comment: This approach does not work with the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline.

Comment: why not? gem 'tiny_mce' supprots rails 3.1

Comment: The tiny_mce gem docs state that it's no longer maintained and that 3.1 is explicitly not supported.

Comment: sad, try to use it without gem, all the gem do is generate javascript filesm which you can download manual.

Comment: I have it working well using https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails with a custom skin inside of activeadmin but have yet to implement image/file uploads.

Comment: you need to send you images as json to tinymce

Comment: This solution works very well! To use it inside active admin simply replace the route for this one:   match "admin/model_name/:id/js_image_list", :action => "js_image_list", :controller => "admin/model_name". Then create an action called js_image_list inside the active admin model file. Configuration for tinyMCE.init is: external_image_list_url : "js_image_list"

Answer (score 1):

It seems like tinymce is definitely supported by rails 3.1.  Here is the link
http://rubygems.org/gems/tinymce-rails

All you have to do is add the following to your Gemfile

```
gem 'tinymce-rails'
```

You have the following options to add to application.js depending on whether you want to use jquery or not

```
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require tinymce
```

Personally I chose jquery so I added this line to the js.coffee file corresponding to my controller/view

```
tinyMCE.init
  mode: 'textareas',
  theme: 'advanced'
```

If you don't want to use jquery you can just add this script to your view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
    mode: 'textareas',
    theme: 'advanced'
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with tinymce and Rails asset pipeline. I have not, also, found a way to start tinymce with increased font size. The default font size is very small.

If you are using twitter bootstrap one fantastic option is:

https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5

If you want something that works with HTML5 I would go with:

http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/

Awesome!